# Stretch UL to div vertically

Tags: html, css

How do I stretch my UL so that this doesn't happen?
[image]

[image]

As you can see, the list ends at the top of the scrollbar and the bottom of it, but doesn't go past the arrow. How do I go about fixing this? The div is set to overflow and holds the list.

```
<div class="thing-box">
  <ul id="thing-ul">
   {{#each thing}}
    <div class="each-thing">
     {{text}}
    </div>
   {{/each}}
  </ul>
</div>


.thing-box {
  height: 300px;
  width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: The only valid element directly inside an `<ul>` is a `<li>` element. Inside that `<li>` you can add a `<div>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was directly adding a div into a `<ul>`.
I replaced the `<ul>` with `<li>` and now it works
Sadly I can't tag a comment as an answer, but thanks Roy.

Comment: I was trying to reproduce your problem, but I couldn't figure out the point. Of course, Roy is right, inside ul > li is the only valid combo. However, I got the same results doing it either way, so I was wondering what was the point...

Comment: Oh, by this chance I discovered that Firefox on Android does not render the scrollbars at all - looks like a bug..